# Trying to return multiple values from react functional component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am trying to return a multiple values from the below method and getting an error like property assignment expected at the `return` statement and my method looks like this below,

```
export const useSectionQuery = (query, resultFieldName, updateState, transform, initialRevisionId) => {

  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);
  let  transformed;
  const { loading, error } = useQuery(query, {
    variables: {
      where: initialRevisionId ? { initialRevisionId } : { isApproved: true },
      order_by: null
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    onCompleted: data => {
     transformed = transform ? transform(data[resultFieldName]) : data[resultFieldName];
      updateState(draft => {
        draft[resultFieldName] = transformed;
      });
      setCompleted(true);
    }
  });
  if (error) return errorRedirectElement(error, resultFieldName);
  return {(!completed || loading) && loadingElement, transformed };
};
```

and getting an error `property assignment is expected` at here in below line

```
 return {(!completed || loading) && loadingElement, transformed }
```

Comment: You're returning an object by using `{}`, but its not in a valid object format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your're not rendering with JSX you need to assign `(!completed || loading) && loadingElement` to a property name

so it should be

```
return {
  element: (!completed || loading) ? loadingElement : null, 
  transformed
}
```

if you're doing it within `render()` you could do this and it would work. Not when returning an object.

```
render() {
  {(!completed || loading) && loadingElement} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React v16.2 introduced another way of returning multiple elements. [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) abstracted in JSX way via just an empty tag. Bare in mind that JSX syntax doesn’t support attributes — use a verbose way if you need so. No extra components needed, no array notation, no keys. Nice!

**You just need to wrap you code around with <React.Fragment> tag in the return statement**

```
const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
    <p>React 16 can return multiple elements ❤️</p>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: can just use <></> as shorthand for <React.Fragement></React.Fragment>